# Setting guttering between sidebar and main content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working with bootstrap and trying to create a gutter between a static sidebar and the main content area.

At the moment the main content is overlapping the sidebar, so I've been messing with the CSS to create a gutter that is even on both sides.

I've not found which setting I need to change in bootstrap-sass but using developer tools I can get this top position correct, but I don't think this is the proper way to do it.

[image]

[image]

when i leave these as the default, the card is moved to behind the sidebar.

[image]

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks